# How to turn a String with square brackets and forward slashes + variables into a regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've tried to get my head around regex, but I still can't get it.

I want to turn the following String + some variables into a regex:

```
"[url href=" + objectId + "]" + objectId2 + "[/url]"
```

I tried the following, since I read somewhere that brackets and slashes need to be escaped:

```
/\[url href=/ + objectId + /\]/ + objectId2 + /\[\/\url\]/g
```

But that isn't working.

I want to use it to replace the whole expression into HTML wherever it matches in a String.

Comment: `new RegExp("\\[url href=" + objectId + "\\]" + objectId2 + "\\[\\\\url\\]")` - would be a start, but you'd need to escape whatever is in `objectId1` and `object2` - what characters can they contain?

Comment: @nnnnnn Every possible character that a URL can have. Numbers, letters, symbols, etc.

Comment: Passing into `new RegExp()` is the way to use strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript - for escaping the values in the variables. Also note that if you want to change the matched text into HTML, presumably an anchor element, you'd need to add some `()` sub matches for `objectId` and `objectId2` in order to extract the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that brackets and backslashes need to be escaped in a regular expression, but you can't create a regex by adding together regex literals like your `/\[url href=/ + objectId + /\]/` attempt. To build a regex dynamically like that you have to use string concatenation and pass the result to `new RegExp()`. So as a starting point for your text you'd need this:

```
new RegExp("\\[url href=" + objectId + "\\]" + objectId2 + "\\[/url\\]")
```

Note all of the double-backslashes - that's because backslashes need to be escaped in string literals, so `"\\["` creates a string containing a single backslash and then a bracket, which is what you want in your regex.

But if you want to extract the matched href and content for use in creating an anchor then you need capturing parentheses:

```
new RegExp("\\[url href=(" + objectId + ")\\](" + objectId2 + ")\\[/url\\]")
```

But that's still not enough for your purposes because `objectId` and `objectId2` could (or will, given the first is a url) contain other characters that need to be escaped in a regex too, e.g., `.+?()`, etc. So here's a function that can escape all of the necessary characters:

```
function escapeStringForRegex(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

We can't just call that function on the whole thing, because you need unescaped parentheses for your capturing sub matches, so just call it on the two variables:

```
var urlRegex = new RegExp("\\[url href=("
                          + escapeStringForRegex(objectId)
                          + ")\\]("
                          + escapeStringForRegex(objectId2)
                          + ")\\[/url\\]");
```

Kind of messy, but seems to do the job as you can see here:

```js
function escapeStringForRegex(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

function createAnchors(str, objectId, objectId2) {
  var urlRegex = new RegExp("\\[url href=(" + escapeStringForRegex(objectId) + ")\\](" + escapeStringForRegex(objectId2) + ")\\[/url\\]", "g");
  
  return str.replace(urlRegex, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var objectId = document.getElementById("objectId").value;
  var objectId2 = document.getElementById("objectId2").value;
  
  document.getElementById("output").value =
    createAnchors(str, objectId, objectId2);
});
```

```css
textarea { width : 100%; height: 80px; }
```

```html
Input:<br><textarea id="input">This is just some text that you can edit to try things out. [url href=http://test.com.au?param=1]Test URL[/url]. Thanks.</textarea>
ObjectId:<input id="objectId" value="http://test.com.au?param=1"><br>
ObjectId2:<input id="objectId2" value="Test URL"><br>
<button>Test</button>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Note that the above searches only for `[url]`s in your string that have the particular href and content specified in the `objectId` and `objectId2` variables. If you just want to change all `[url]`s into anchors regardless of what href and text they contain then use this:

```
.replace(/\[url href=([^\]]+)\]([^\]]+)\[\/url\]/g, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
```

Demo:

```js
function escapeStringForRegex(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

function createAnchors(str) {
  return str.replace(/\[url href=([^\]]+)\]([^\]]+)\[\/url\]/g, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  document.getElementById("output").value = createAnchors(str);
});
```

```css
textarea { width : 100%; height: 80px; }
```

```html
Input:<br><textarea id="input">Testing. [url href=http://test.com.au?param=1]Test URL[/url]. Thanks. Another URL: [url href=https://something.com/test?param=1&amp;param2=123]Test URL 2[/url]</textarea>
<button>Test</button>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's like:

```
var rx = new RegExp('\\[url\\shref='+objectId+'\\]'+objectId2+'\\[\\/url\\]');
```

Comment: This won't work, because backslashes have meaning in string literals.

Comment: I thought those were quotes. You changed your comment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Before I edited they were backticks containing a single backslash, but that didn't display properly so I replaced it with the word "backslashes". (You'd need four in a row for `\\\\url`, except that the OP has since edited the question to make it `/url`.)

Comment: The thing is the strings are evaluated before they are concatenated to form the expression you desire.

Comment: Yes. Which is why you'd need the string `'\\\\url'` to create a regex with `\\url`. (Except the OP changed it to `/url` so that doesn't need escaping in a string, only in a regex literal.)

Answer (score -2):

```
new RegExp("[url href=" + objectId + "]" + objectId2 + "[\url]")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: This won't work. You'd need to escape the square brackets and double-escape the backslash, and possibly escape whatever is is in `object1` and `objectId2`...